# Draw line in direction of raycaster in three.js

Tags: three.js

In three.js, I'm using PointerLock controls the make a basic first person shooter.
I use

```
function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {
  var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
  mouse3D.normalize();
  controls.getDirection( mouse3D );
  raycaster.set( controls.getObject().position, mouse3D );
  var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects );
  ...
}
```

to detect a collision with an object, which means you "shot" the object.

Now, I want to visualize the path the bullet took. I was thinking about drawing a line from where the user is looking to, in direction of the raycaster, but I can't figure out how to do this... Anyone who can help me? I'm new to three.js, never thought drawing a line would be this hard.

**Update:**
I'm trying to draw a line using:

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices.push(...);
geometry.vertices.push(...);
var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
scene.add(line);
```

but I can't figure out what to put in place of the "..." . How can I detect which point the line should go to? And how to determine which point it starts from? The player is able to move and even jump so the starting point is always different too.

Comment: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Drawing-lines

Comment: Thanks for that reference. I know now how to draw a line, but still can't figure out how to address my problem. I've updated my question.

Comment: I think you just need to send the `push()` method the starting point and end point (Vectors). The first one probably being your camera position `geometry.vertices.push(camera.position)`. The second one being the first point of intersetion returned from the intersectObjects function. `geometry.vertices.push(intersects[0].point)`. I have not use the Raycaster so have not tested this, but it will be something like it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following (using r83):

```
    // Draw a line from pointA in the given direction at distance 100
    var pointA = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 );
    var direction = new THREE.Vector3( 10, 0, 0 );
    direction.normalize();

    var distance = 100; // at what distance to determine pointB

    var pointB = new THREE.Vector3();
    pointB.addVectors ( pointA, direction.multiplyScalar( distance ) );

    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    geometry.vertices.push( pointA );
    geometry.vertices.push( pointB );
    var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color : 0xff0000 } );
    var line = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
    scene.add( line );
```

Codepen at: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/evNqGy

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
function animate_Line(frame, totalFrames) {

    //Calculate how much of the line should be drawn every iteration
    var delta = lineDistance/(totalFrames);  
    var deltaSpeed = delta * frame;

    for(var i=0; i<f_Ray_List[0].length; i++) {
        for(var j=0; j<f_Ray_List[1].length; j++) {
            //Change Offsets
            line.geometry.vertices[1].y = line.geometry.vertices[0].y - deltaSpeed;

            //Update Rays = true (Make FRT rays draw-able)
            line.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
        } 
    }
}
```

where `frame` is the current frame (a counter in your animate function), `totalFrames` would be the amount of frames that the line would take to be animated. The `lineDistance` can be calculated by using this:

```
 lineDistance = line.geometry.vertices[0].y - line.vertices[1].y; //Add this line where you create the line object.
```

and remember to call `line.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;` in every line individually, so that the line would able to be animated.

Notice that this is only based on Line.y axis. This would not be great at first. I'm currently working on converting this to Polar coordinates instead but I have no idea what is going on hahah.

[image: DEMO]